# how to perform Drag and drop functionality in selenium webdriver if Destination location is missing until element actual moves to that location

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, webdriver

After moving an element manually a new li HTML tag is created under ol tag. Before moving an element when I try to use mouseover on expected destination path web driver throws NoSuchElementException exception as Destination location is missing until element actual moves to that location[image]

Comment: Share website and code

Comment: You can find the similar link as  [link](http://demoqa.com/draggable/)
and code as :
`getDriver().get("http://demoqa.com/draggable/");
  WebElement we = getDriver().findElement(By.id("ui-id-5"));    //Click on draggable+Sortable tab placed at left panel
  we.click();
  WebElement we1 = getDriver().findElement(By.id("draggablebox"));
  WebElement we2 = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='sortablebox']//li[3]"));
  Actions act = new Actions(getDriver());
  act.clickAndHold(we1).build().perform();
  act.moveToElement(we2).build().perform();
  act.release(we2).build().perform();`